# Superwebsocket server setup fails in windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, websocket, supersocket.net

I have created a server with Superwebsocket(http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com) in .Net and works fine in my windows 7 and any other PC with windows 7, but it is not working in windows 8.

It fails at setup() method.

```
web_socket_server = new WebSocketServer(); 
if(!web_socket_server.Setup("Any", 3014)){
      Console.WriteLine("Setup Failed!");
}
```

I disabled the firewall, ran as administrator, changed the port number, but nothing worked.
Can any one advice me or tell me a way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Are you running the same executable? or you mean you created a new project in Windows 8?

Comment: Yes same executables created in windows 7. Program runs, but web_socket_server.Setup("Any", 3014) return false.

Comment: That is funny. Would you try with my websocket server? http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/ I know it works in Windows 2012, so it should be fine.

Comment: I have used this on Windows 8 without issue.